# How to abort cancel a file reading FileReader

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using this code:

```js
document.getElementById("fileToUpload").onchange = function () {
  var reader = new FileReader();
    
  reader.onload = function (e) {
   // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
   $("#image").show();
   document.getElementById("image").src = e.target.result;
  };
    
  // read the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
};
```

to get the preview of an image. If the user press the cancel button the selected file will be null so I need to hide the `img`.
What's the needed code to get an empty target result or a cancel of the dialog?

Comment: i meant if he press cancel in the image selection dialog , like for example if he press cancel here http://www.listary.com/images/features/quick-switch-folder-file-dialog.png

Comment: Than it's unclear what dialog you're talking about, cause `<input type="file">` already provides you with a **Cancel** button in the system's browse dialog.

Comment: Yeah i mean THAT button. When you press the system browse dialog cancel button the preview doesnt change to an empty one, i want to use the event of pressing that button to .hide() it

Answer (score 2):

Use
`FileReader.abort()` to **abort** the process of reading a large file
`FileReader.onabort` to **detect** that the process has been aborted (hide #image)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

In the example below the `abort()` will be triggered synthetically by a `setTimeout` just for demo. You can use a button click to trigger the `abort` (also in this example)

```js
const elFile = document.querySelector("#file");
const elAbort = document.querySelector("#abort");
const elImage = document.querySelector("#image");

const reader = Object.assign(new FileReader(), {
  onabort() {
    console.log("Reading aborted!");
    elImage.classList.add("u-hidden"); // Hide image
  },
  onload(evt) {
    console.log("Reading complete!");
    elImage.src = evt.currentTarget.result;
    elImage.classList.remove("u-hidden"); // Show image
  },
  onerror: console.error
});

elFile.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  // Read the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(evt.currentTarget.files[0]);
  // JUST FOR THIS DEMO! EMULATE ABORT AFTER 1ms. (Remove this later!)
  setTimeout(() => reader.abort(), 1);
});

// INSTEAD OF USING THE ABOVE 1ms setTimeout DEMO ABORT
// LET THE USER MANUALLY ABORT FILE READING
elAbort.addEventListener("click", () => {
  reader.abort(); // This is how you abort a file reading!
});
```

```css
/* Utility classes */
.u-hidden { display: none; }

#image { max-height: 120px; }
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*"><br>
<button id="abort" type="button">ABORT READING</button><br>
<img id="image" class="u-hidden" src="#!" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option you can try:

```
(function () {
    $("#fileToUpload").on('change', function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
      $("#image").css('display', '');
      $("#image").attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    // read the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  });

  $('#btnUpload').on('click', function () {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to upload this Image?')) {
        // your upload code here
    } else { // user clicked the cancel button
        $("#fileToUpload").replaceWith($("#fileToUpload").clone());
      $("#image").css('display', 'none').attr('src', '');
    }
  });
})();
```

See example jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fictus/dsgjtmfq/

Comment: `"Are you sure you want to upload this Image?"` seems a **bad UI** leading to a bad UX. Positive processes should be encouraged not stopped. Aborting a reading of a large file makes sense. Pausing an expected program flow makes not.

Comment: I upped your comment :) I was trying to read between the lines of the question when he asked `to get an empty target result or a cancel of the dialog`, so in my mind I have no clue what he refers to as "dialog" and assumed a "confirm" dialog. So I tried to answer according to his question.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can refre this [Link here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cJpUhhd3Jj8X2dWQvbyT)

**JS**

```
 // Add your javascript here
    $(function(){
       $('#blah').hide();
    function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                   $('#blah').show();
                    $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#imgInp").change(function(){
            $('#blah').hide();
            readURL(this);
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>
    <!-- Put your html here! -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you include some explanation why this might help OP in his problem. Avoid posting link and code only answers